# WebApi Routing causes 404 (Not Found) response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So, this is a simple one. I have done this in the past. But, it seems that I am missing something.

`WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Attribute routing.
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

`Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

`SomeController.cs`

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class SomeController: ApiController
{
    [Route("some")]
    [HttpGet]
    private HttpResponseMessage GetSome(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, when I call: `http://localhost:54699/api/some`, I get the following `404`:

> {   "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>   URI 'http://localhost:54699/api/some'.",   "MessageDetail": "No
>   type was found that matches the controller named 'some'." }

Folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is your controller method private this should be public

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class SomeController: ApiController
{
    [Route("some")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSome(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from that What is `MessageDetail` you don't include it in your example is that what model is being bound to from the `GetSomeController` because if so you may need to add an attribute to retrieve that data, that has changed since the last version, if it is from body on a get method that will be required

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes to notice the silly things.

Comment: Yeah your telling me, you don't know how many times, I've forgetten to add empty read routes, or forget to inherit from controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` after MVC's `FilterConfig`. This is a standard caveat with WebAPI attribute routing.

Comment: I don't remember the actual sequence, but I'm 99% sure it has to do with the order WebApi is configured.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I remember this from an old project. But, this time was the private modifier that got there for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you have /api in your routing configuration file.

you have mentioned /api as route prefix for controller and then action is "some".

the uri to "some" should be

```
http://localhost:<port>/api/api/some
```

Comment: Nope. Still not found

Answer (score 0):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/some")]
public class SomeController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSome(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

You method GetSome is private. Also, I'll modify the RoutePrefix attribute as in the code snippet to avoid rewriting the Route Attribute on each method.